# How to consume SSL web service in WPF. how WPF download SSL certificate

Tags: wpf, web-services, ssl

I have a WPF application that requires to consume an SSL web service. How can I download SSL certificate in my WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

YOU. CAN. NOT.

it is not an aplpications place to download and install ssl certificates - it is the responsibility of the comptuer admin to make sure the root certificate is trusted OR NOT.

Basically - no self signed certificates, no shady root certificates.